# wait for deferred() and return its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to overwrite the default confirm()

I can get it to work, but only by modifying my calls to confirm(), which I don't want to do.

I currently use confirm like so:

```
if(confirm('are you sure?')){
    //they clicked to confirm so do stuff here
}
```

I am overriding the confirm method like this:

```
 window.confirm = function(message){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    //build my own confirm box
    // add message
    //add a button, to resolve the defer:
    button.on('click', function(){
        defer.resolve('true');
    });

    return defer.promise();
 }
```

but this doesn't work, the confirm() method return true straight away before the user clicks any buttons, firing the code within the if() block.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Short answer: you can't - `confirm` is a blocking function (along with `prompt` and `alert`).   Anything involving your own dialog won't be, so anything that uses this will need to pass in a callback function or work with the promise etc.

Comment: `confirm('are you sure?').done(function(){...});` But like James said, it won't be modal

Comment: @A.Wolff Oh, you can make them modal - but the OP wants to make it work without changing anywhere that currently calls `confirm`.  That's the bit that won't work :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe By modal i meant blocking javascript code execution

Comment: @A.Wolff Fair enough - I've not seen "modal" in that context before!